# Conditional model binding in angularJS based from the drop down selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Say that I have a dropdown that is bound to a model property that will be checked to determine the model that will bound to my textbox.

```
<select ng-model="searchType">
   <option value="Id">Id</option>
   <option value="Firstname">Firstname</option>
</select>
```

whatever the user picked, The search will be based off that and it could either be `searchQuery.id` or `searchQuery.Firstname`

It is displayed like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:sortColumn:sortDescending | filter:searchQuery">
        <td>{{ user.Id }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.Firstname }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.LastName }}</td>
</tr>
```

I tried to use the code from a similar topic that uses the `getter/setter` but I can't seem to make it work.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can be `search` object inside controller like `$scope.search = {}` and then place search object over that filter.

```
<select ng-model="searchType">
   <option value="Id">Id</option>
   <option value="Firstname">Firstname</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control" ng-model="search[searchType]" ng-disabled="!searchType.length"/>

<tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:sortColumn:sortDescending | filter: search">
    <td>{{ user.Id }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.Firstname }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.LastName }}</td>
</tr>
```

---

Though above will work but if you change dropdown it will now work as intended. So do clear `search` object when you change the dropdown value. So that search would be more accurate.

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WXDoICKLK0gFEjsU6R0I?p=preview)

Comment: Made a plunker based on this good answer for testing purposes: https://embed.plnkr.co/MDlUpFFRKxQRg7rCO61v/

Comment: Oh wow!  I did not know about this!  It does partial matching as well!

Comment: @NathanBeck thanks for the plunkr, there was little bug in my code, when you change dropdown `search` object was preserving property value. So I clear than on dropdown change.

Comment: @Zach & Nathan thanks for involvement in comment section, I really appreciate you guys, Cheers & Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

if I'm not mistaken, you can do this :

```
ng-repeat="user in users | .... | filter:conditionalSearch()"
```

and then in your controller / link add this :

```
$scope.conditionalSearch = function() {
    if ($scope.searchType == 'id') return { .. condition 1 .. }
    if ($scope.searchType == 'firstName') return { .. condition 2 .. }
}
```

Comment: Close!  the `conditionalSearch` function is a function that returns a function with the current user passed in!  `$scope.conditionalSearch = function() { return function (currentUser) { return currentUser[$scope.SearchType] == $scope.criteria; } };` but make sure the searchType matches the user property names - including case.

Comment: @Zach please don't make drastic changes to the code of other answers. Instead, post your own answer if you think it might benefit others and the thread as a whole.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Forgive me.  I felt his answer was close enough to warrant the change and the credit rather than posting my own.